# Need to strip CSV Column Number Data of Letters - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, replace

I am working on a .csv that has columns in which numerical data includes letters. I want to strip the letters so that the column can be a float or int.

I have tried the following:

- using the loop/def process to strip object columns of string data, in "MPG" column and leave only numerical values.
- it should print the names of the columns where there is at least one entry ending in the characters 'mpg'

#### CODING IN JUPYTER NOTEBOOK CELLS:

#### Step 1:

```
MPG_cols = []
for colname in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object']:  
    if df[colname].str.endswith('mpg').any(): 
        MPG_cols.append(colname)
print(MPG_cols)
```

- using `.str` so I can use an element-wise string method
- only want to consider the string columns

#### THIS GIVES ME OUTPUT:

[Power]. #good so far

#### STEP 2:

```
#define the value to be removed using loop

def remove_mpg(pow_val):
    """For each value, take the number before the 'mpg'
    unless it is not a string value. This will only happen
    for NaNs so in that case we just return NaN.
    """
    if isinstance(pow_val, str):
        i=pow_val.replace('mpg', '') 
        return float(pow_val.split(' ')[0]) 
    else:
                    return np.nan

    position_cols = ['Vehicle_type'] 

for colname in MPG_cols:
    df[colname] = df[colname].apply(remove_mpg)

df[Power_cols].head()
```

#### The Error I get:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-45b7f6d40dea> in <module>
     15 
     16 for colname in MPG_cols:
---> 17     df[colname] = df[colname].apply(remove_mpg)
     18 
     19 df[MPG_cols].head()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in        apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f,     convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-37-45b7f6d40dea> in remove_mpg(pow_val)
      8     if isinstance(pow_val, str):
      9         i=pow_val.replace('mpg', '')
---> 10         return float(pow_val.split(' ')[0])
     11     else:
     12                     return np.nan

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'null'
```

I applied similar code to a different column and it worked on that column, but not here.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Bests,

Comment: Can you include a sample of the DataFrame in your question? This will help us recreate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(['$2', '3#', '1mpg']).str.replace('[^0-9]', '', regex=True))
```

0    2
1    3
2    1
dtype: int64

for complete solution,

```py
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    if(df.iloc[:,i].dtype == 'object'):
        df.iloc[:,i] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,i].str.replace('[^0-9]', '', regex=True))
df.dtypes
```

**Select columns not to be changed**

```py
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    # 'colA', 'colB' are columns which should remain same.
    if((df.iloc[:,i].dtype == 'object') & df.column[i] not in ['colA','colB']):
        df.iloc[:,i] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,i].str.replace('[^0-9]', '', regex=True))
df.dtypes
```

Comment: Wow thank you !!! -- Ok the range solution did the job --- the MPG, and the MPH, and the dollar symbol from a currency column, BUT it worked a bit too well. I had one Column of Object data which include car model names, and the code overwrote that data. Is there way to restore  only that column, or do I need to import that column from the original .csv ?

Comment: If its only 1 column, you can do `if( (df.iloc[:,i].dtype == 'object') & (df.columns[i] != 'Column') )`, or for multiple, you can use `not in` []. I will update the answer, let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: Afternoon Roach, thank you very much for replying.       I am not a programmer just beginning, so I am a bit confused.  Are u saying to use this the code snippet you provided to RESTORE the missing column of data?  Or are you saying I should havre run your snippet instead of what I didi, to exclude the column?      My current need is to restore the missing column of data --get the make and model names back.

Comment: You'll have to re-run your code and load data back into python. Always keep the raw data. I think you just need to load data, once to overwrite information its not available, you can always create new data frames and once you have the result, only then replace/overwrite. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think  you would need to revisit the logic for function `remove_mpg` one way you can tweak as follows:

```
import re
import numpy as np
def get_me_float(pow_val):
    my_numbers = re.findall(r"(\d+.*\d+)mpg", pow_val)
    if len(my_numbers) > 0 :
        return float(my_numbers[0])
    else:
        return np.nan
```

for example, need to test the function.

```
my_pow_val=['34mpg','34.6mpg','0mpg','mpg','anything']
for each_pow in my_pow_val:
    print(get_me_float(each_pow))
```

output:

```
34.0
34.6
nan
nan
```

nan

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `converters` paremeter to the `read_csv` function to strip the extra characters when you load the csv file?

```
def strip_mpg(s):
    return float(s.rstrip(' mpg'))

df = read_csv(..., converters={'Power':strip_mpg}, ...)
```